# In Perl, how can I use Tie::IxHash with a dictionary while 'use strict' is on?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a hash that preserves the order that the keys are added.  Under section "Create a hash and preserve the add-order" of [this page](http://www.perlcircus.org/hashes.shtml), it gives a snippet that modifies a hash so when you do `keys` it returns the keys in the order that you inserted them into the hash.

When I do the following snippet:

```
use strict;
our %foo;
use Tie::IxHash;
tie (%foo, Tie::IxHash);
```

It fails with:

```
Bareword "Tie::IxHash" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /nfs/pdx/home/rbroger1/tmp.pl line 4.
Execution of /nfs/pdx/home/rbroger1/tmp.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

How can I get Tie::IxHash to work when `use strict` is on?

**dsolimano's Example worked.**

```
use strict;
our %foo;
use Tie::IxHash;
tie (%foo, "Tie::IxHash");

$foo{c} = 3;
$foo{b} = 2;
$foo{a} = 1;

print keys(%foo);
```

prints:

```
cba
```

without the `tie...Tie::IxHash` line it is

```
cab
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second argument to `tie` is a string, so try

```
use strict;
our %foo;
use Tie::IxHash;
tie (%foo, 'Tie::IxHash');
```

Comment: sure enough.  That worked.  Updating th ticket with the full example

Comment: FWIW, the CPAN doc is:

    `# simple usage`
    `use Tie::IxHash;`
    `tie HASHVARIABLE, Tie::IxHash [, LIST];`
No mention of second arg being a string!  (But using quotes works.)

Comment: Look at perldoc - http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html, `tie VARIABLE, CLASSNAME, LIST`, and the examples all use strings for `CLASSNAME`.  I'd say it's an issue with the `Tie::IxHash` documentation on CPAN.

Answer (score 5):

Using quotes eliminates the error:

```
use strict; 
our %foo; 
use Tie::IxHash; 
tie (%foo, "Tie::IxHash");
```

It is not mentioned in the POD, but it is used in the [examples](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GSAR/Tie-IxHash-1.21/t/ixhash.t) on CPAN.

See also [tie](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html).